# 127.0.0.1 and localhost error - first REST API, MacOS

Tags: python, rest, local, macos-sierra

I'm learning python and I am writing REST API code:

```
from flask import Flask,jsonify,request,render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

stores = [{
    'name': 'My Store',
    'items': [{'name':'my item', 'price': 15.99 }]
}]

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

#post /store data: {name :}
@app.route('/store' , methods=['POST'])
def create_store():
    request_data = request.get_json()
    new_store = {
      'name':request_data['name'],
      'items':[]
    }
    stores.append(new_store)
    return jsonify(new_store)
    #pass

#get /store/<name> data: {name :}
@app.route('/store/<string:name>')
def get_store(name):
    for store in stores:
        if store['name'] == name:
            return jsonify(store)
    return jsonify ({'message': 'store not found'})
    #pass

#get /store
@app.route('/store')
def get_stores():
    return  jsonify(stores)
    #pass

#post /store/<name> data: {name :}
@app.route('/store/<string:name>/item' , methods=['POST'])
def create_item_in_store(name):
    request_data = request.get_json()
    for store in stores:
        if store['name'] == name:
            new_item = {
                'name': request_data['name'],
                'price': request_data['price']
             }
            store['items'].append(new_item)
            return jsonify(new_item)
    return jsonify ({'message' :'store not found'})
    #pass

#get /store/<name>/item data: {name :}
@app.route('/store/<string:name>/item')
def get_item_in_store(name):
    for store in stores:
        if store['name'] == name:
            return jsonify( {'items':store['items'] } )
    return jsonify ({'message':'store not found'})

    #pass

app.run(port=5000)
```

In the terminal the result is:
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

In the browser it gives:
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

After pasting the address to the browser in the terminal there is:

```
[2017-07-17 06:54:35,234] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "app2.py", line 12, in home
    return render_template('index.html')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 133, in render_template
    return _render(ctx.app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 869, in get_or_select_template
    return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 830, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 804, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 113, in load
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 57, in get_source
    return self._get_source_fast(environment, template)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 85, in _get_source_fast
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jul/2017 06:54:35] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jul/2017 06:54:35] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

I use macOS Sierra

Comment: This should be the first thing to investigate: `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html` It is looking for the `index.html` template file. Did you create it? Is it in the correct spot (i.e.: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#rendering-templates)

Comment: I had the file in the folder named template. I have changed to templates and it works. Thank mate